# How do I center this span element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a picture slideshow on a website that I want to have a certain span length, while also centering it. It has a span 9, but I can't get it to center even with the text-align:center attribute.

```
<div class="span9">
  <section id="slider">
   <div class="fullwidthbanner-container" style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="fullwidthbanner" style="text-align:center;">
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>
```

Here's the css:

```
#slider {
margin-top: 100px;
text-align: center; 
}

.fullwidthbanner-container{
width: 100%;
position: relative;
max-height: 700px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}

.sliderbanner-container{
width: 100%;
position: relative;
max-height: 600px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}

.fullwidthbanner ul li,
.sliderbanner-container ul li {
list-style: none;   
text-align: center;
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/uu6dch71/5/

however, it isn't really showing up on the preview. The site for reference is http://jmvanwyck.com

Comment: Give `.span9` a `width` and `height` and use `margin:0 auto;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.span9` is a block container with a fixed width, you can center it with

```css
.span9 {
    width: 870px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none; /* default value */
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! 

what exactly does margin and float mean?

Comment: @NathanMiranda `float:none` disables the `float:left` that you had. `float:none` is the "normal" behaviour, and floating elements are too complex to be explained in a comment. Margin is just margin, `margin: 0 auto` sets `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to `0` (no margin), and `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` (which does the horizontal centering).